# Java: Can Function have a parameter for an array of a specific length?

Tags: java, arrays, function, parameter-passing

I am making a subroutine that will convert a 8-bit binary number into a int value. I want it to take as a parameter a int array with a length of 8 (to represent the binary number) and **reject arrays of any other length**. Is the possible?

Comment: No. You can check the length in your method.

Comment: You can check for the length of the given array at the start of the method and throw an exception / return null.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to ensure the length of an array at compile time. You have to use

```
if(my_array.length != 8){
    throw new Exception("Array must have a length of 8.");
}
```